# How to trigger method on UITextField

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I have 5 UITextFields next to each other. Each one is supposed to capture a digit of a pin number. This is how i'm limiting input to 1 character and moving the cursor onto the next text field.

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
    {
        if (self.pin1.text.length == 1 && range.length == 0) [self.pin2 becomeFirstResponder];
        if (self.pin2.text.length == 1 && range.length == 0) [self.pin3 becomeFirstResponder];
        if (self.pin3.text.length == 1 && range.length == 0) [self.pin4 becomeFirstResponder];
        if (self.pin4.text.length == 1 && range.length == 0) [self.pin5 becomeFirstResponder];
        return YES;
    }
```

Once the user enters there last digit in the last text field (pin5) I'd like add some functionally to check the pin. For now an NSLog will do. How do I do this?

If I add this line of code to the end of shouldChangeCharactersInRange. You have to click a number twice to capture the 5th digit.

```
if (self.pin5.text.length == 1 && range.length == 0) NSLog(@"Pin %@, %@, %@, %@, %@", self.pin1.text, self.pin2.text, self.pin3.text, self.pin4.text, self.pin5.text);
```

Comment: According to your pattern, wouldn't you just add another if statement to check if text has been added to pin5?

Comment: Having 5 text fields seems very wieldy...

Comment: @CrimsonChris - Good thinking, please see edit above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    if (string.length > 0 &&  textField.text.length < 1) {
        textField.text = string;
        if (textField == self.pin1) [self.pin2 becomeFirstResponder];
        else if (textField == self.pin2) [self.pin3 becomeFirstResponder];
        else if (textField == self.pin3) [self.pin4 becomeFirstResponder];
        else if (textField == self.pin4) [self.pin5 becomeFirstResponder];
        else if (textField == self.pin5) NSLog(@"Pin %@, %@, %@, %@, %@", self.pin1.text, self.pin2.text, self.pin3.text, self.pin4.text, self.pin5.text);
    }
    return (textField.text.length + string.length) <= 1;
}
```

Comment: This does work, the the 5th click it displays the pin. For some reason it starts in pin2 and ends up putting 2 chars in pin5?

Comment: @user3626407 Updated it.

Comment: Thanks very much, This now populates pin1 and pin2 on when clicking on the number pad once. Also pin5 is still accepting 2 chars. We are nearly there

Answer (score 0):

How about adding this final statement?

```
if (self.pin5.text.length == 1 && range.length == 0) {
    NSLog(@"Hey there!");
}
```

You could also want to make all of your fields disabled at start (except the first one), so that you can enable them one by one.

Comment: I've tried this and for some strange reason you have to click the 5th digital twice for it to call this code.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line just before the return statement:

```
if (self.pin5 == textField) {
    self.pin5.text = string;
    [self.pin5 resignFirstResponder]; // You can hide the keyboard if you like
    NSLog(@"Last text field");
}
```

Comment: I've tried this and for some strange reason you have to click the 5th digital twice for it to call this code.

Comment: Same again, have to click the 5th digit on the number pad twice.

Comment: @user3626407 I just checked it out and it works fine for me. I clicked the number, it appeared in the text field and the keyboard is dismissed with nslog. Please check it again.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this. Set up your textfields like so.

```
[self.pin1 addTarget:self 
              action:@selector(textFieldDidChange:) 
    forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
...
[self.pin5 addTarget:self 
              action:@selector(textFieldDidChange:) 
    forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
```

Then in another method do the following:

```
-(void)textFieldDidChange:(id)sender {
    if (sender == self.pin1) [self.pin2 becomeFirstResponder];
        else if (sender == self.pin2) [self.pin3 becomeFirstResponder];
        else if (sender == self.pin3) [self.pin4 becomeFirstResponder];
        else if (sender == self.pin4) [self.pin5 becomeFirstResponder];
        else if (sender== self.pin5) {

            [self.pin5 resignFirstResponder];
            NSString *pinString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ %@ %@ %@", self.pin1.text, self.pin2.text, self.pin3.text, self.pin4.text, self.pin5.text];
            NSLog(@"%@", pinString);
        }
}
```

Comment: I wish Apple would just add this action to UITextFieldDelegate.

Comment: @CrimsonChris yeah it's odd they would have a *should* change characters but not a *did* change characters.

Comment: They've added it to UITextView already. I'm sure they'll add it _eventually_.